# Как растянуть сайдбар до футера?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, адаптивная-верстка

[css](http://pastebin.com/1y4N4t7p)

[html](http://pastebin.com/SX6GRks4)

Не работают:

```
min-height: 100%; 
height: 100%;
```

Как растянуть сайдбар до футера?

Comment: лучше код на jsfiddle залейте

Comment: @dizballanze https://jsfiddle.net/jsm58qLe/

Comment: Aydar2015 jsfiddle.net/jsm58qLe по следующему отображению непонятно что вам необходимо?

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться со статьёй [Как создать краткий, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы задать 100%-ую высоту необходимо, чтобы высота родителя была явно определена (конкретным значением `height: 1000px`), или всем родитеским элементам должен быть присвоен стиль: `height: 100%;` и еще указать:

```
html, root, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 95%;
  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  \ margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.main-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main-wrapper div {
  float: left;
  min-height: 300px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.container {
  width: 600px;
  background: ;
}
.container p {
  width: 90%;
  color: blue;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 190px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background: ;
  margin-left: 8px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.sidebar p {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: blue;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>

  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel viverra ex. Curabitur rutrum tellus urna, vitae gravida dui lacinia quis. Aenean id magna vel diam bibendum finibus. Etiam posuere augue sit amet augue sodales, egestas pellentesque
        turpis tempor. Sed nibh mi, finibus et lacinia ac, ultrices a enim. Sed volutpat ultrices congue. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Phasellus dapibus diam et nisl ultricies, hendrerit tincidunt
        augue fringilla. Ut fringilla ut odio gravida facilisis. Suspendisse vel eros dui. Vivamus tempus vehicula tortor eu porta. Nulla eget porttitor felis, nec dapibus leo. Nulla lacinia nisi vel suscipit eleifend. Integer porta varius nibh, eget
        efficitur dui bibendum at. Aenean eu dictum elit. Etiam aliquam sodales luctus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In hendrerit magna vitae augue rhoncus, vel ultricies mauris auctor. Nullam
        aliquam mauris in odio fermentum viverra. Aliquam facilisis in magna vitae efficitur. Maecenas porttitor velit dolor, sed elementum arcu tristique sed. Aliquam at elementum risus. Curabitur in interdum velit, finibus bibendum ante. Sed venenatis
        eu est in gravida. Quisque pharetra, sem convallis egestas pulvinar, ex felis faucibus nisl, quis lobortis dui lorem id lacus. Nam sed enim ex. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam eleifend arcu at sapien hendrerit
        porta. Morbi sit amet nisi est. Quisque semper erat a pellentesque cursus. Nullam efficitur vestibulum justo, non luctus massa sodales nec. Donec commodo feugiat lectus, a vestibulum mi varius vel. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur laoreet placerat
        justo, id consectetur ex ultricies eu. Donec hendrerit at nibh nec blandit. Suspendisse rhoncus volutpat lectus et aliquet. Mauris sed eleifend sem. Ut a porta arcu. Proin eu risus felis. Nam non tristique ligula. Aenean magna magna, rhoncus vitae
        faucibus non, mollis ac magna. Etiam scelerisque blandit libero ac commodo. Vestibulum non massa viverra, elementum diam quis, fermentum nisl. Aenean vulputate tempus varius. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam semper velit arcu, nec faucibus nisi porttitor
        at. Nulla a molestie nibh. Aliquam auctor odio vel porta sagittis. Suspendisse potenti.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel viverra ex. Curabitur rutrum tellus urna, vitae gravida dui lacinia quis. Aenean id magna vel diam bibendum finibus. Etiam posuere augue sit amet augue sodales, egestas pellentesque
        turpis tempor. Sed nibh mi, finibus et lacinia ac, ultrices a enim. Sed volutpat ultrices congue. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Phasellus dapibus diam et nisl ultricies, hendrerit tincidunt
        augue fringilla. Ut fringilla ut odio gravida facilisis. Suspendisse vel eros dui. Vivamus tempus vehicula tortor eu porta. Nulla eget porttitor felis, nec dapibus leo. Nulla lacinia nisi vel suscipit eleifend. Integer porta varius nibh, eget
        efficitur dui bibendum at. Aenean eu dictum elit. Etiam aliquam sodales luctus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In hendrerit magna vitae augue rhoncus, vel ultricies mauris auctor. Nullam
        aliquam mauris in odio fermentum viverra. Aliquam facilisis in magna vitae efficitur. Maecenas porttitor velit dolor, sed elementum arcu tristique sed. Aliquam at elementum risus. Curabitur in interdum velit, finibus bibendum ante. Sed venenatis
        eu est in gravida. Quisque pharetra, sem convallis egestas pulvinar, ex felis faucibus nisl, quis lobortis dui lorem id lacus. Nam sed enim ex. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam eleifend arcu at sapien hendrerit
        porta. Morbi sit amet nisi est. Quisque semper erat a pellentesque cursus. Nullam efficitur vestibulum justo, non luctus massa sodales nec. Donec commodo feugiat lectus, a vestibulum mi varius vel. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur laoreet placerat
        justo, id consectetur ex ultricies eu. Donec hendrerit at nibh nec blandit. Suspendisse rhoncus volutpat lectus et aliquet. Mauris sed eleifend sem. Ut a porta arcu. Proin eu risus felis. Nam non tristique ligula. Aenean magna magna, rhoncus vitae
        faucibus non, mollis ac magna. Etiam scelerisque blandit libero ac commodo. Vestibulum non massa viverra, elementum diam quis, fermentum nisl. Aenean vulputate tempus varius. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam semper velit arcu, nec faucibus nisi porttitor
        at. Nulla a molestie nibh. Aliquam auctor odio vel porta sagittis. Suspendisse potenti. Integer scelerisque commodo nisi ac egestas. Aenean scelerisque eros dui, at blandit nunc efficitur interdum. Duis eget accumsan lacus. Nam eu consectetur
        diam. Sed accumsan nibh tortor, in ultricies mauris volutpat a. Aliquam tempor scelerisque orci ac finibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis et venenatis felis. Nam mauris nunc, blandit
        ac arcu non, rhoncus convallis nisl. Mauris pretium nisi et malesuada scelerisque. Maecenas in augue in sem malesuada luctus. Nunc eget mauris eget arcu ornare consectetur. Proin vehicula feugiat malesuada. Donec pretium malesuada hendrerit. Integer
        tellus arcu, efficitur quis felis sed, pellentesque rutrum eros. Donec nisl arcu, feugiat a mauris luctus, eleifend volutpat nunc. Vivamus commodo, sem sed auctor consectetur, velit tortor vehicula est, et gravida urna odio in nisi. Vestibulum
        ipsum libero, pellentesque sit amet magna eu, faucibus euismod nisi. Donec a lacus arcu. Ut vitae ultricies sem. Suspendisse in volutpat erat. Praesent metus diam, volutpat vel lorem eget, faucibus condimentum neque. Praesent sed ipsum sit amet
        eros scelerisque faucibus sed quis lorem. Sed eu purus ut ex gravida venenatis. Proin vitae porttitor augue. Cras porttitor, massa a mattis molestie, urna mi condimentum nisl, eu vehicula neque urna vitae urna. Suspendisse dolor nunc, elementum
        ac posuere ut, maximus facilisis ipsum. Nullam ut velit magna. Vestibulum vestibulum gravida consectetur. Aliquam ac elit id mauris maximus pulvinar. Cras quis venenatis leo. Cras aliquet vestibulum urna, feugiat rutrum justo tincidunt ut. Nunc
        sit amet libero posuere elit suscipit consectetur quis a est. Duis eleifend urna pretium, blandit lacus eu, tristique lacus. Morbi justo dui, pulvinar vitae nunc non, condimentum imperdiet nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit. Nullam leo massa, lacinia sit amet porttitor eget, condimentum in orci. Mauris feugiat efficitur libero, et rhoncus mi ultrices eu. Etiam pellentesque neque ut ex fringilla, at faucibus magna vestibulum. Proin luctus nec ligula non volutpat.
        Curabitur feugiat placerat tellus, at semper eros bibendum at. Maecenas euismod dignissim lacus, sit amet malesuada erat hendrerit ut. Aliquam ac sollicitudin metus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse tincidunt ex tincidunt vulputate tempor. Pellentesque
        habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque ac ex vitae turpis posuere luctus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/qhf2575y/

вот так у меня получилось , вот только если sidebar не пуст

Comment: Используйте кнопку "вставить фрагмент" (Ctrl+M) для добавления кода. Сообщение должно быть самодостаточным, ссылки на JSFiddle и подобные ресурсы могут служить только дополнением.

Answer (score 0):

```css
main{
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #d6d6d6;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
main aside,nav{
    float:left;
    min-height:400px;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
aside{
    width:350px;
    border-right:1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
nav{
    width:150px;
   }
.post{
    width:90%;
    height:auto;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#F4F4F4;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <aside>
        <div class="post">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
         <div class="post">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div> 
         <div class="post">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
          <div class="post">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>       
        
    </aside>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Ссылка</li>
             <li>Ссылка</li>
             <li>Ссылка</li>
             <li>Ссылка</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</main>
```

вот так устроит ? в просмотре видно что nav на всю высоту - хотя это  зрительный обман